# Moving elements in array in vue data isn't triggering recompute of compueted element

Tags: javascript, vue.js

In my vue app I have

```
  data: {
      emailData: JSON.parse('#{{@mail.data}}')
  },
  computed: {
      emailJson: function () {
          return JSON.stringify(this.emailData);
      }
  },
  methods: {
      addBlock: function (type) {
          this.emailData.elements.push({type: type, data: ''})
      },
      removeBlock: function (index) {
          this.emailData.elements.splice(index, 1)
      },
      moveBlock: function (direction, index) {
          if (direction === 'up' && index > 0) {
              let temp = this.emailData.elements[index - 1]
              this.emailData.elements[index - 1] = this.emailData.elements[index]
              this.emailData.elements[index] = temp
          } else if (direction === 'down' && index < this.emailData.elements.length) {
              let temp = this.emailData.elements[index + 1]
              this.emailData.elements[index + 1] = this.emailData.elements[index]
              this.emailData.elements[index] = temp
          }
      }
  }
```

If I run `moveBlock('up',2)` I can see the data in `emailData` has changed in the expected way but `emailJson` still shows the data before modifications. If I later call `addBlock` the changes of both the previous `moveBlock` and `addBlock` now show in `emailJson`.

What reason would be causing `addBlock` and `removeBlock` to trigger the computed value to change but `moveBlock` does not.

Comment: Vue.js can not detect this change. Use either `Vue.set` or `splice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems my issue is caused because VueJS can not detect changes to an array when set by index. As described in the docs https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Caveats